# Get attributes from tags in XML document

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, tags

I have a XML file with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Bill_Spec DN="s" DP="68734">
<cash_Share CS="1391/01/01" CL="1391/01/31" CB="1000" CI="200" CD="100" CX="50" CC="40" CT="1046"/>
<insur_Share IS="1391/02/01" IL="1391/02/31" IB="2500" II="120" IT="2380"  />
</Bill_Spec>
```

I wrote this code but I want get attributes seperately like a variable

```
require('XMLParser.class.php');

$xml = new XMLParser;

$output = $xml->parse('Iranpars.xml');

print_r($output);
```

How do I get all attributes from these tags like DN or CS?

Comment: Your question is not clear, because it's unknown what `XMLParser.class.php` contains and/or what the `XMLParser` object does. It's like you would ask about unknown code or functions nobody knows about.